# How to parse dynamic nested paths in spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi all I am writing a spring controller to printout the contents of a directory so my controller signature is

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/listdir/{dirname}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DirectoryItem>> listDirectory(@PathVariable String dirname){
List<DirectoryItem> directories = util.getDirectoryItems(rootFolder + dirname);
```

I call it with a get:

```
/listdir/dirname
```

and it returns a json of the contents of the directory. eg
file1,
file2,
dir1,
dir2,
and so on.

So next what i want is that in the view if the user clicks a directory name, the same method is called.
This time i imagine the call would be

```
listdir/dirname/dir1
```

and so on for the next would be

```
listdir/dirname/dir1/childdir
```

Does anyone know what's the correct way of accomplishing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wildcard in a mapping like this

```
@GetMapping("listdir/**")
public String listDirectory(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String dirname = request.getRequestURI().split(request.getContextPath() + "/listdir/")[1];
    // ...
}
```

but basically for such request you should not use path parameters at all. Instead of this just send the parameter through the request parameter

```
@GetMapping("all")
public String listDirectory(@RequestParam("dirname") String dirname) {
    // ...
}
```